# C++ Builder reading TMemoryStream buffer to void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++builder

I'm trying to copy contents of TMemoryStream buffer to void pointer, below you can see sample code which is not working - void buffer is empty, but textbox contains valid size - I checked it with winrar size. Following code creates exe file, but it's size is 0.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TMemoryStream* ms = new TMemoryStream();
    Download->Get("http://rarlab.com/rar/wrar521pl.exe",ms);
    this->Edit1->Text = ms->Size;
    void* buffer = malloc(ms->Size );
    ms->Read(buffer,ms->Size);
    FILE* pFile = fopen("test.exe","wb");
    fwrite(buffer,4,ms->Size,pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    delete ms;
}
```

Also, I know that I can easily save contents of TMemoryStream buffer to file, but I need its contents as void pointer, so I wrote following code to test it out.

Comment: malloc and delete in the same function... you know you can't mix those right?

Comment: Why are you fwriting 4 * ms Size?  Simply 1 * ms Size is enough

Comment: Download is undefined on `Download->Get(...)`

Comment: @Roberto dowload is not undefined - I named tldHTTP "Download"

Comment: @Grantly this worked! I was pretty sure that 2nd param is sizeof buffer type, well I was wrong

Comment: `TMemoryStream` has a `SaveToFile()` method: `Download->Get(..., ms); ... ms->SaveToFile("test.exe");` But then, why not download using a `TFileStream` instead?

Comment: Nice :) Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: @RemyLebeau did u read my question? I wrote, that I know how to save file directly from memorystream, but I wanted to ask why I cant copy it to void buffer

Comment: @encoreleet: Then you should not have included that code in your example to begin with. Your code to read the stream is (almost) correct, but your code to write the data to file was wrong.

Comment: @Borgleader actually you can, so long do not use `delete` on things which were `malloc`'d etc. (which this code does correctly)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Theres a malloced buffer, passed to a newed stream, the stream is deleted, but not the buffer. I assumed owning semantics of the buffer by the stream. (and since its a C++ class, i also assumed it would call delete on said buffer)

Comment: @Borgleader there's no owning semantics, `Read` is a memcpy-like function.  `buffer` is leaked. Even if there was owning semantics, it makes no difference how the stream was allocated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to read from the stream is *almost* correct.  You are not resetting the stream's `Position` property to 0 before reading, so you are actually reading from the end of the stream, where there is no data to read.

Try this:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TMemoryStream* ms = new TMemoryStream();
    try
    {
        Download->Get("http://rarlab.com/rar/wrar521pl.exe", ms);
        ms->Position = 0; // <-- ADD THIS
        Edit1->Text = ms->Size;
        void* buffer = malloc(ms->Size);
        if (buffer)
        {
            ms->ReadBuffer(buffer, ms->Size);
            // ms->SaveToFile("test.exe");
            FILE* pFile = fopen("test.exe", "wb");
            if (pFile)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, 1, ms->Size, pFile);
                fclose(pFile);
            }
            free(buffer);
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete ms;
    }
}
```

Or, simply don't allocate a separate buffer, use the stream's own buffer directly instead:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TMemoryStream* ms = new TMemoryStream();
    try
    {
        Download->Get("http://rarlab.com/rar/wrar521pl.exe", ms);
        Edit1->Text = ms->Size;
        void* buffer = ms->Memory;
        // ms->SaveToFile("test.exe");
        FILE* pFile = fopen("test.exe", "wb");
        if (pFile)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, ms->Size, pFile);
            fclose(pFile);
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete ms;
    }
}
```